# How correct add plugins to ckeditor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, ckeditor

I download plugin audio from ckeditor site, unpack it to path `../public/assets/ckeditor/plugins/Audio`

In `config.js` in `EXTRA_PLUGINS` params i add `audio`.

In `MIN_TOOLBAR` i append audio button
 name: 'document',

```
items: ['Source', 'Audio']
```

When i start project i dont find audio button. What i make wrong?

ps. I use this gem https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor